# What is the default username and password for SonarQube?

Tags: security, login, default-settings

What is the default username and password for a fresh installation of SonarQube? Or how do you create a user?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

username: admin

password: admin

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication#Authentication-AdminCredentialsDefaultAdminCredentials

Comment: It was just too hard for them to put that in the doc I guess...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in SonarQube 6.

Comment: @IgorG. I'm using SonarQube 6.6 with [docker compose](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes.md) and [admin/admin](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2016/10/14/good-old-adminpassword/) works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are like me and have installed Sonarqube 6.4 using jdk 9 / jre 9 the login will always fail. This is due to the fact that java 9 is not supported. Please change the java version to 8 that is supported.

You can also point to a different java version in the conf/wrapper.conf file:

```
wrapper.java.command=/some/path/to/proper/jdk8
```

Valid jdk/jre options are found here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements

Answer (score 1):

In Bitnami's official [Docker implementation](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/sonarqube#configuration), the defaults are:

username: `admin`

password: `bitnami`

This worked for me on SonarQube 7.9.1.